# setState is not updating inside componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: reactjs

I feel like I am calling setState in the proper manner, but want to make sure I didn't make a call in the wrong place. Seeing if anyone can spot the error. In the console log the state is holding the previous value, not the new cleared value. Here is the code I have:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.value !== this.state.value && typeof nextProps.value !== 'undefined'){
        let changeVal = nextProps.value;
        let changeDisplay = nextProps.value;
        if(this.props.entryType === 'date') changeVal = Moment(nextProps.displayValue).format(this.props.format).toString();
        if(this.props.entryType === 'currency'||this.props.entryType === 'number'){
            if(isNaN(parseFloat(changeVal))){
                changeVal = 0;
                changeDisplay = 0;
            }
        }
        if(this.props.entryType === 'drop' || this.props.entryType === 'boolean'){
            if(this.props.options) {
                this.props.options.map(x => {
                    if (x.value == changeVal || x.sortOrder == changeVal){
                        changeDisplay = x.label;
                        changeVal = x.value;
                    }
                })
            }
        }
        this.setState({value: changeVal, displayValue: changeDisplay, selectValue:{value:changeVal, label:changeDisplay}}, ()=>{
            console.log("current displayValue",this.state, nextProps, this.props)
        });
    }
}
```

Clearly I am calling console after setState, but the value does not update.

EDIT: Thanks for the responses. I am going to attempt to rip apart the props update state method. I created a drag and drop system, where items can be dragged in and out of groups. Works great, but it has a Container >  Tree > Item > QueryValue components in that hierarchy. The problem here comes in that Container needs to know the entire tree, to be able to build it out, but the edits to the contents occur in QueryValue. So I have a method I pass through the chain which allows me to notify Container of any changes. But I may need to decouple the Container data from the QueryValue data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is quite complex so I would suggest trying to refactor it.

But in any case, I would suggest using "componentDidUpdate"

- because "componentWillReceiveProps" is deprecated and can lead to side-effects and complex state flow, which favor bugs in your code

---

React docs (for "componentDidUpdate"):

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

---

React docs (for "UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps"):

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops

---

```
Note: 

Using this lifecycle method often leads to bugs and inconsistencies, and for that reason it is going to be deprecated in the future.

If you need to perform a side effect (for example, data fetching or an animation) in response to a change in props, use componentDidUpdate lifecycle instead.

For other use cases, follow the recommendations in this blog post about derived state.

If you used componentWillReceiveProps for re-computing some data only when a prop changes, use a memoization helper instead.

If you used componentWillReceiveProps to “reset” some state when a prop changes, consider either making a component fully controlled or fully uncontrolled with a key instead.

In very rare cases, you might want to use the getDerivedStateFromProps lifecycle as a last resort.
```

Comment: "consider either making a component fully controlled or fully uncontrolled with a key instead" My scenario is definitely a prop comes into the component and I want to update it with the new prop. What is the pattern with this quote though? I am not following.

Comment: never mind, I found it https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Comment: @tcoulson happy it helped. Please mark it approved for others who will get here

Comment: "Keys are usually used for dynamic lists but are also useful here", why can't reactjs have another prop for this? Seems like overloading the responsibility of key. I will mark it as the solution after I implement and find it to be the correct solution. I upvoted both answers for now.

Comment: This is correct answer - but I am making my QueryValue component into a Fully Controlled Component. I found I was already passing data out of the component, and sending the state, so not tracking state inside my component works better.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by @Tzook Bar Noy the React team strongly suggest against using `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method. You can use `componentDidUpdate` but it is also considered a bad practice to use `setState` inside that function: it could lead to infinite loop `componentWillUpdate -> setState -> componentWillUpdate -> setState -> etc` if you don't manage your boundaries correctly.

I suggest, as you are not using instance methods in your code, to use the new `getDerivedStateFromProps` static method. This method is called with current props and state when component mounts, and when component updates. It uses the returned object to optionally update component state.

Check in react docs if it applies to your use case. Interesting article:  https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Your code could look like so:

```
    getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
        if (props.value !== state.value && typeof props.value !== 'undefined') {
            let changeVal = props.value
            let changeDisplay = props.value
            if (entryType === 'date')
                changeVal = Moment(props.displayValue)
                    .format(format)
                    .toString()
            if (
                entryType === 'currency' ||
                entryType === 'number'
            ) {
                if (isNaN(parseFloat(changeVal))) {
                    changeVal = 0
                    changeDisplay = 0
                }
            }
            if (
                entryType === 'drop' ||
                entryType === 'boolean'
            ) {
                if (options) {
                    options.map(x => {
                        if (x.value == changeVal || x.sortOrder == changeVal) {
                            changeDisplay = x.label
                            changeVal = x.value
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
            return {
                value: changeVal,
                displayValue: changeDisplay,
                selectValue: { value: changeVal, label: changeDisplay }
            }
        }
        return null
    }
```

Comment: what version of reactjs did that come out with?

Comment: It appeared in `16.3` and I believe there was a small issue fixed in `16.4`

Comment: I am using 16.1 so will need to upgrade.